# TypeDescriptor doesn't return members from inherited interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, typedescriptor

my problem is that TypeDescriptor doesn't return members from inherited interfaces, is this how it is supposed to be working ? or is it a bug ?

```
 [TestFixture]
    public class DescriptorTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
                                                                    // count = 1 
            Assert.AreEqual(2, TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(IFoo)).Count);
     // it is going to fail, the Id is not going to be returned
        }

        public interface IEntity
        {
            int Id { get; set; }
        }

        public interface IFoo : IEntity
        {
            string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't a bug. From the [ECMA CLI specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm):

> **8.9.11 Interface type derivation**
>
> Interface types can require the
>   implementation of one or more other
>   interfaces. Any type that implements
>   support for an interface type shall
>   also implement support for any
>   required interfaces specified by that
>   interface. This is different from
>   object type inheritance in two ways:
>
> - Object types form a single inheritance tree; interface types do
>     not.
> - Object type inheritance specifies how implementations are inherited;
>     required interfaces do not, since
>     interfaces do not define
>     implementation. Required interfaces
>     specify additional contracts that an
>     implementing object type shall
>     support.
>
> To highlight the last difference,
>   consider an interface, `IFoo`, that
>   has a single method. An interface,
>   `IBar`, which derives from it, is
>   requiring that any object type that
>   supports `IBar` also support `IFoo`.
>   It does not say anything about which
>   methods `IBar` itself will have.
>
> **8.10 Member inheritance**
>
> Only object types can inherit
>   implementations, hence only object
>   types can inherit members (see
>   §8.9.8). While interface types can be
>   derived from other interface types,
>   they only "inherit" the requirement to
>   implement method contracts, never
>   fields or method implementations.

**Edit...**

If you want to get the properties of an interface, including those of its ancestors, then you could do something like this:

```
var properties = typeof(IFoo)
                     .GetProperties()
                     .Union(typeof(IFoo)
                                .GetInterfaces()
                                .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties()));
```

Comment: In support of this answer, Reflectoring the implementation shows (I think) that `GetProperties` *does* walk up the `.BaseType` tree of the type being examined - but `typeof(IFoo).BaseType` is null, so the walk stops straightaway.

Comment: @AakashM do you know hot to get all the properties of IFoo ?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. I think it is a bug since it works for inherited properties on classes!

Comment: what's the BindingFlags.Instance for ?

Comment: Means it is not static. It will not work if you do not include it.

Comment: typeof(IFoo).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Length also returns 1