# Read properties of derived as well as base class

Tags: c#

I have 2 classes

Class 1

```
public class baseClass
{
   public string prop1{get;set;}
   public string prop2{get;set;}
   public string prop3{get;set;}
}
```

Class 2

```
public class derived:baseClass
{
    public string prop4{get;set;}
}
```

Now when i try to read properties with the following code, but as its obvious it only returns derived class's properties

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(derived));
```

Is there any way with which i can read properties of derived as well as baseclass

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeDescriptor doesn't return members from inherited interfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031267/typedescriptor-doesnt-return-members-from-inherited-interfaces)

Comment: But this worked for me and returns both base and derived properties! Just one think the `base` for class name is invalid. You should choose another name.

Comment: In C# your class did even compile? Because `base` is not a valid class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use *Reflection*?

```
  PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(derived).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

  Console.Write(String.Join(Envrironment.NewLine, properties.Select(p => p.Name)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it works:

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Derived));

for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(properties[i].Name);
}
```

Returns:

> prop1 prop2 prop3 prop4

And as I have founded in http://referencesource.microsoft.com/, `GetProperties()` will internally call [`GetProviderRecursive`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/TypeDescriptor.cs,71b89f5ece6e94c8):

```
/// <devdoc>
///     This method returns a type description provider, but instead of creating
///     a delegating provider for the type, this will walk all base types until
///     it locates a provider.  The provider returned cannot be cached.  This
///     method is used by the DelegatingTypeDescriptionProvider to efficiently
///     locate the provider to delegate to.
/// </devdoc>
internal static TypeDescriptionProvider GetProviderRecursive(Type type) {
    return NodeFor(type, false);    
}
```

I don't know for what purpose you are trying to fetch properties, but as @Dmitry Bychenko answered, you can use `Reflection`. You can check the differences of the both ways in this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402239/typedescriptor-getproperties-vs-type-getproperties).

*Update to your answer:*

```
 var result = typeof(Derived).GetProperties()
                .Select(prop => new
                {
                    prop.Name,
                    prop.PropertyType
                });
```

Comment: did you use "PropertyDescriptorCollection"? Could you post a complete example. Because when i tried but got only one property

Comment: @MARKANDBhatt WHich `.net` version are you using?

Comment: @MARKANDBhatt Are you sure all proeprties are `public`?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to read property name as well as its type

```
var properties = typeof(T).GetFields();
foreach (var prop in properties)
{
  var name =  prop.Name;
  var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.FieldType.FullName) ?? prop.FieldType.FullName);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the problem was a base interface rather than a base class?